# Zip and extension

Tags: vbscript, zip

How to hide or don't display the compressing zip processing form. It's possible the extension use *.dat but still Zip format.

```
ArchiveFolder "sub\foo.zip", "..\baz"

Sub ArchiveFolder (zipFile, sFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

        Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _
                 .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
            WScript.Sleep 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`CopyHere`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866.aspx) method has an optional second parameter for flags that control the behavior of the method:

> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> Folder.CopyHere(
>   vItem,
>   [ vOptions ]
> )
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> [...]
>
> *vOptions* [optional]
>
> Type: Variant
>
> Options for the copy operation. This value can be zero or a combination of the following values. These values are based upon flags defined for use with the fFlags member of the C++ SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure. Each Shell namespace must provide its own implementation of these flags, and each namespace can choose to ignore some or even all of these flags. These flags are not defined by name for Visual Basic, VBScript, or JScript, so you must define them yourself or use their numeric equivalents.
>   Note  In some cases, such as compressed (.zip) files, some option flags may be ignored by design.
>
> (4) Do not display a progress dialog box.
>   ...

Try

```
.NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items, 4
```

but beware that the flag might be ignored for zip files (not sure about it).

Comment: I was changed but still display a progress dialog box.
    CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items, 4